# MYSQL probably a join

Tags: mysql

In our organization, members who achieve certain goals can earn different awards. 
Management wants to recognize members who earned certain awards for the first time ever in this year, as opposed to members who may have earned a given award again this year.  We can't select only those who have won exactly one award of any type, because they may have earned two or more awards (for the first time ever) this year.

I have tried various approaches but they all match too many members.  A simple procedural language search might start with all members who earned one or more specified awards this year, and then reject the ones who earned ANY awards in any previous year, but I can't come up with the SQL to do it.

The awards Table is about 400K records, with columns: award, awarddate, Membername.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT memberName FROM awards WHERE YEAR(awardDate) = '2012' AND (memberName NOT IN (SELECT memberName FROM awards WHERE (YEAR(awardDate) < '2012')))
```

Comment: Works, but with a rather lengthy runtime (over a minute).  Any optimization that come to mind?

Comment: OK, I created a temporary table to hold the results of the table in the WHERE clause, and it is now very fast.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just brainstorming, but perhaps something like this would work?

```
SELECT `Membername` 
FROM `award_table` 
WHERE (YEAR(awarddate) = 2012) &&
      (`Membername` NOT IN (SELECT `Membername` 
                            FROM `award_table` 
                            WHERE (`awarddate` BETWEEN `1950-01-01` AND `2011-12-31`))
```

**EDIT:** Just re-read and see you have 400k rows... this way might be too resource expensive.

Comment: Use `YEAR(awarddate) = 2012`, not some crazy `LIKE` operation with wildcards :)

Comment: Yes of course!  Always typing too fast for my own good.  Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: It won't be run often, so performance is less of a consideration, but good point.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do something involving a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause and a subquery that looks for matching awards in prior years, but it's hard to provide a specific answer without knowing more about your database schema.

Another possibility:  `GROUP BY` the columns that identify the award, take the `min(awarddate)` of each group, and filter out values before this year in the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: Here's my most recent try.  The inner SELECT run by itself gives expected results, but the outer join returns no results.

SELECT Thisyear.Membername, a.Award, a.Awarddate, count(*) as oldawards

FROM awards a

INNER JOIN (

 SELECT Membername

    FROM awards

    WHERE  award='cc' AND awarddate > '2011-12-31'

    ORDER BY Membername

) Thisyear

USING (Membername)

WHERE a.Awarddate < '2012-01-01'

GROUP BY a.Membername

HAVING oldawards = 0